# Does the unique existential quantifier commute with the existential quantifier?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Given some function involving two variables, $\mathit p(x,y)$, is the formula $$\mathit \exists!x\exists yp(x,y)$$ equivalent to $$\mathit\exists y\exists!xp(x,y)$$
I have tried writing out the formal definition for the unique existential quantifier, but I get stuck simplifying the statement when the unique quantifier is first. I have also tried giving $\mathit p(x,y)$ some meaning and talking through it, but I can't decide if they mean the same thing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In the second instance, do you perhaps mean a formula and not a function?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, they do not commute.

Consider for example the nonnegative reals as a linear order. Then $$\exists x\exists !y(y\le x)$$ is true (take $x=0$), but $$\exists!y \exists x(y\le x)$$ is false since for *every* $y$ there is some $x$ with $y\le x$.

---

This becomes less surprising when we "unpack" $\exists!$. There are a few ways to do this, but I think the simplest is to view "$\exists !x\varphi(x,...)$" as an abbreviation for "$\exists x\forall z(\varphi(z,...)\leftrightarrow x=z)$." Then we have:

- "$\exists x\exists!y\varphi(x,y)$" is an abbreviation for $$\exists x\exists y\forall z(\varphi(x,z)\leftrightarrow y=z),$$
- while "$\exists!y\exists x\varphi(x,y)$" is an abbreviation for $$\exists y\forall z[(\exists x\varphi(x,z))\leftrightarrow y=z].$$

This has a clear instance of swapping $\forall$ and $\exists$ *(in fact, it's even messier than that - unpack "$\leftrightarrow$" ...)*, so we should expect them to be inequivalent in general.

*(There are of course other ways to unpack "$\exists!$," but they'll all yield the same general picture: despite the symbol suggesting only existentiality, it's hiding a very important universal quantifier, and so the usual dangers of $\forall/\exists$-switching carry over to $\exists!/\exists$-switching.)*

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.

Comment: To make this (and other similar statements involving two quantifiers) intuitive: imagine a table where the rows represent the possible values of $x$, the columns represent the possible values of $y$, and we put a tick mark in a cell if the corresponding pair $(x, y)$ satisfies $p(x,y)$. Then the first formula means "there is exactly one non-empty row", while the second formula means "some column has exactly one marked cell" - a weaker statement.

Comment: @IliaSmilga That's a useful way to put things.